# How to get rid of SourceMapConcat build error in emberjs?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I am always getting below error when I try to run `ember server --proxy http://localhost:16000/` command. How do I solve this error? I have tried deleting `tmp`,`build`,`bower_components` & `node_modules` folder and tried with fresh workspace, but still facing the same issue. This is a dev environment, and this is working fine on production, but it is no longer working on my dev system.

```
Build Error (SourceMapConcat)

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-aeXF7Gds.tmp/bower_components/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js'

Stack Trace and Error Report: /tmp/error.dump.619dc9ea64ab42159355cbebc854fe80.log
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "antiscroll": "git://github.com/Addepar/antiscroll#e0d1538cf4f3fd61c5bedd6168df86d651f125da",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "~3.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.4",
    "ember-bootstrap-table": "^0.1.2",
    "pace": "^1.0.2",
    "spin.js": "2.1.0",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^2.1.1",
    "socket-io-client": "^1.4.5",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.1",
    "seiyria-bootstrap-slider": "~6.0.6",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "select2": "3.5.2",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "pagination-pager": "3.2.0",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "mark.js": "^8.9.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "bootbox": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ember": "> 1.5.0-beta.3"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "iidiq-ui",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Small description for project goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.4.1",
    "ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-bootstrap-table": "1.0.0",
    "ember-changeset-validations": "1.2.6",
    "ember-cli": "^2.11.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker": "^0.5.6",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.6",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-is-package-missing": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-nouislider": "^0.13.0",
    "ember-cli-pace": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sass": "6.1.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cp-validations": "3.3.2",
    "ember-data": "^2.11.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-inline-svg": "0.1.7",
    "ember-link-action": "0.0.35",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-moment": "7.3.0",
    "ember-page-title": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-power-select": "^1.5.0-beta.0",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.1.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-select-2": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-source": "~2.11.0",
    "ember-table": "0.9.2",
    "ember-tether": "0.4.1",
    "ember-toastr": "1.6.2",
    "ember-tooltips": "2.9.0-beta.0",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.3.0",
    "ember-ui-blocker": "0.3.0",
    "ember-validations": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^2.0.2",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
    "handlebars-helpers": "0.8.2",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.10",
    "pagination-pager": "^3.1.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.5 || 6.* || >= 7.*"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "align-text": "^0.1.4",
    "arr-diff": "^4.0.0",
    "array-unique": "^0.3.2",
    "ember-cli-build-date": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-math-helpers": "^2.1.0",
    "handlebars-helpers": "^0.8.2",
    "is-ip": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I am using the following

ember-cli: 2.18.2
node: 8.11.2
os: linux x64

**Update** added full stack trace from **/tmp/error.dump.619dc9ea64ab42159355cbebc854fe80.log** file

```
=================================================================================

ENV Summary:

  TIME: Mon Apr 22 2019 22:45:26 GMT+0530 (IST)
  TITLE: ember
  ARGV:
  - /usr/bin/node
  - /usr/bin/ember
  - server
  - --proxy
  - http://localhost:16000/
  EXEC_PATH: /usr/bin/node
  TMPDIR: /tmp
  SHELL: /bin/bash
  PATH:
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/bin
  - /bin
  - /usr/local/games
  - /usr/games
  - /home/rick/local/node-v6.17.1-linux-x64/bin
  - /home/rick/local/p4v/bin
  - /home/rick/local/vscode/bin
  - /root/local/node-v6.17.1-linux-x64/bin
  - /root/local/p4v/bin
  - /root/local/vscode/bin
  PLATFORM: linux x64
  FREEMEM: 701112320
  TOTALMEM: 8167378944
  UPTIME: 10209
  LOADAVG: 1.4736328125,0.8818359375,0.9248046875
  CPUS:
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz - 2710
  ENDIANNESS: LE
  VERSIONS:
  - ares: 1.14.0
  - cldr: 32.0.1
  - http_parser: 2.8.1
  - icu: 60.2
  - modules: 57
  - napi: 3
  - nghttp2: 1.31.1
  - node: 8.11.2
  - openssl: 1.1.0h
  - tz: 2017c
  - unicode: 10.0
  - uv: 1.24.1
  - v8: 6.2.414.54
  - zlib: 1.2.11

ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-liYGowJd.tmp/bower_compo$
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at SourceMap.addFile (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:77:33)
    at headerFiles.forEach.file (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:204:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Concat.concat.end.concat (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:202:26)
    at /home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:431:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SourceMap.end (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:418:12)
    at Concat._doLegacyBuild (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:187:24)
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-liYGowJd.tmp/bower_components/blockUI/jquery.bl$
  - errorMessage: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `SourceMapConcat` plugin. 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-liYGowJd.tmp/bower_components/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js'
  - errorType: Build Error
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
    - treeDir: [undefined]
  - message: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `SourceMapConcat` plugin. 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-liYGowJd.tmp/bower_components/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js'
  - name: Error
  - nodeAnnotation: Vendor JS
  - nodeName: SourceMapConcat
  - originalErrorMessage: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-liYGowJd.tmp/bower_components/blockU$
  - stack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-liYGowJd.tmp/bower_components/blockUI/jquery$
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at SourceMap.addFile (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:77:33)
    at headerFiles.forEach.file (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:204:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Concat.concat.end.concat (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:202:26)
    at /home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:431:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SourceMap.end (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:418:12)
    at Concat._doLegacyBuild (/home/rick/Perforce/IIDIQ-UI/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:187:24)

=================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working for me now.

I deleted bower_components, added `"blockUI": "malsup/blockui",` in bower.json, and ran `bower install` again, before running

`ember server --proxy http://localhost:16000`

Ref: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2517#issuecomment-395717660